# R - glm - how to deal with missing values

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

I am looking at the effect of fertiliser on plant nutrients.

One column is fertiliser type (ntype), there are 4 options: AS, SN, OR, and None.
For each type there are different amounts/quantities (nquant):

- AS: 48, 96, 144
- SN: 48, 96
- None: 0
- OR: this is where the problem lies, we don't know how much is in OR, it is an unknown (currently left as blank/NA values).

The model I was attempting was looking at fibre and these fertilisers:

```
summary(glm(fibre~(ntype/nquant),data=mydata))
```

The issue is, if I run this, the model appears to ignore OR and we get as below. How should I treat this? I will be adding some extra terms to the model (binary inputs and year).

I also don't understand why nformAS isn't a row - are the other 3 are being compared to that?

Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: What is `/` doing in the GLM formula? I don't know this and cannot find it.

Comment: What does your response variable `fibre` mean? Is it whole or real numbers? What range?

Comment: @Tomas Fibre is a continuous variable (essentially a percentage to 2dp), normally distributed.

"/" is for nesting I believe.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, your model omits the first category of the categorical variable ("AS") and that's what Intercept is for; the other categories are compared to the first one, as you correctly guessed.
2. Your response variable: if it is percentage, you probably need logistic regression (family binomial) with two response variables which create the ratio; or, use `lm` and normal regression, but certainly not the default family=poisson which you are using when you not specify the `family` parameter.

Don't know about the nesting. It looks like R didn't accept the NA values and removed them.

Comment: Thank you, for the time, it's greatly aprpeciated.

 On the first point, I've now used dummy.coef just so I can see the omitted variables. I know they're supposed to be 0.000, it just helps with clarity as it's in a table.

I'll look into point two. There are actually 6 response variables that overall make up 100% so sure I'll hit more snags on the way!!!

I was hoping, with the NA in the nesting, that it would include OR as a broad categorical factor and then, giving a coefficient at that level and then doing second coefficients for ntype/nquant - but alas.